# Prevent auto focus on tinymce in angular 2

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

Can anyone help me how to prevent auto focus in angular 2.

I don't have idea how to do it in angular 2, but I am able to do it jquery:

```
$('form *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();
```

Comment: So how would you do it in JavaScript? Show that and maybe we can help integrate that into angular.

Comment: $('form *:input[type!=hidden]:first').focus();

Comment: That's jQuery...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app module replace the module as bellow

TinymceModule.withConfig({'auto_focus':false,})

Answer (score 0):

While facing above issue in latest angular, to fix this issue,

i changed [init]="{" inside <editor tag
to [init]="{ auto_focus:false"
above step, resolved issue of setting default focuss on tinymce editor.
My requirement to disable the default cursor, so that user can't remove the editor body content right after loading the editor.